# which control should I Use for display like this format

Tags: asp.net

I want to display data in aspx page like this format.

Product Name     Mobile
Qty Rate:     100
Unit Rate:     125
           A1     A2     A3     A4     Total

Red     10     20     30     40     100

Blue     10     20     30     40     100

Green   10     20     30     40     100

```
     Total     300
```

Product Name     Car
Qty Rate:     120
Unit Rate:     150

B1     B2     B3     B4     Total

Red     10     20     30     40     100

Blue     10     20     30     40     100

Green   10     20     30     40     100

```
                   Total     300
                   Grand Total:     600
```

I have one datatable with this value.
I want to display in page but i have't any idea about which control should i use?
Plz Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GridView` contorl inside another `GridView` (nested). Take a look at [Creating a Nested GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: but How to calculate Total and Grand Total in it.

Comment: @ManojSavalia you should calculate them before sending the values to the asp.net control and show them, if you have a problem with calculating those values ask another question about it.